# Community detection from a graph taking an edge weight and a vertex attribute into account

Tags: r, networking, cluster-analysis, graph-theory, igraph

Is there any community detection argorithm/function which can deal with edge weight and discrete node attribute in igraph/R?

I am sorry if I am asking an idiotic question due to lack of theoritical background, but I am looking for a function/algorithm which can detect communities from a graph which contains edge weight (i.e., tie strength between nodes) and nodes with discrete values (i.e., nationality of each node=person) so that it can analyze characteristics of each community, for instance, a specific node attribute (i.e., nationality) forumulate dense community but others are more sparse. The graph in my actual data is undirected.

As far as I confrimed vignette of `igraph` package, some of community detection algorithms in `cluster_` family seems to take only edge weight into acctount. Some other options such as `walktrap.community`, `fastgreedy.community`, `multilevel.community`, `cluster_louvain`, etc., seem not dealing with a node attribute as well.

Comment: "all community detection algorithms in cluster_ family" This is not true. Check the documentation of each. Some don't use weights and not all of them interpret weights in the same way. "Some other options" This are not separate functions, just older deprecated names of the same `cluster_` functions. Don't use the old names, they are going away soon.

Comment: You are asking to consider weights and vertex attributes but don't say _how_ you want to take them into account. The usual way would be to convert vertex attributes into edge weights by computing some sort of similarity between vertices. The specifics depend on what data you have, what the interpretation of the attributes is, and how you want to take these attributes into account. You should read up on the various methods and see if the specific data you have fits how they work.

Comment: You can start with the concept of modularity and see if the weighted version of modularity makes sense for the specific edge weights you have.